# Apparently support floating point index array

Tags: python, numpy

I think this error manifested when i went from numpy v1.11 to v1.12

The original code was converted from Matlab to Python and something to with I think this error manifested when i went from numpy v1.11 to v1.12

The original code was converted from Matlab to Python and something to with floating point vs integer index errors 
Apparently FP is not supported. 
If thats the error - where should the change be made

My error message

---

```
outline_mask = get_outline_mask(mask_str, image.shape[0], image.shape[1])
  File "/var/www/html/code_drop/dicomutils/utils.py", line 136, in get_outline_mask

img[(list(y), list(x))] = 1
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

My code snippet is

---

```
def get_outline_mask(p,     rows, cols):  # Get outline mask     of the marked area
    p2 = p.replace('(',     '[').replace(')',']')
    xy = json.loads('[' + p2 + ']')
    # Subtract 1 because python     is 0-based
    xy =         np.array(xy).astype('float').round() - 1
    # Limit to image region
    x = xy[:, 0].clip(0, cols -    B1)
    y = xy[:, 1].clip(0, rows - 1)
    # close the loop
    x = np.r_[x, x[0]]
    y = np.r_[y, y[0]]

    # Missing points
    x_add = []
    y_add = []
    for i in xrange(len(x) - 1):
        if get_distance(x[i],     y[i], x[i + 1], y[i + 1]) > 1.4142:
            line =     get_line(x[i], y[i], x[i + 1], y[i + 1])
            if len(line) > 2:
                line_x =    map(lambda z: z[0], line)[1:-1]
                line_y = map(lambda z: z[1], line)[1:-1]
                x_add += line_x
                y_add += linee
```

Comment: If floating point not allowed in index arrays - should the specifications for the array index be int

Comment: While earlier versions of `numpy` allowed floats as indices in some cases, the current one does not.  You need to identify which index is giving the problem, and correct it.

Comment: _If thats the error - where should the change be made_ Can you be more specific? Have you done any debugging? What do/don't you understand from that error message?

Comment: I don'tsee `img[(list(y), list(x))] = 1` in the code snipit.

Comment: The current numpy version is 1.18.  In Py3 the bare `map` calls are wrong; that's an old Py2 style.

Comment: # Missing points
    x_add = []
    y_add = []
    for i in xrange(len(x) - 1):
        if get_distance(x[i], y[i], x[i + 1], y[i + 1]) > 1.4142:
            line = get_line(x[i], y[i], x[i + 1], y[i + 1])
            if len(line) > 2:
                line_x = map(lambda z: z[0], line)[1:-1]
                line_y = map(lambda z: z[1], line)[1:-1]
                x_add += line_x
                y_add += line_y

    x = np.r_[x, x_add]
    y = np.r_[y, y_add]

    img = np.zeros((rows, cols))
    img[(list(y), list(x))] = 1

    return img

Comment: could not find another to add to code snippet   sorry about lines running into each other

Comment: Look at `x` and `y` right before the error line.

Comment: can you specify the exact change?